# Why do I get [INFO] Worker Exiting (pid: 2) when deploying cloud run service with docker? (On VSCode with cloud code extension)

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

I'm really new to this stuff, I'm a 16 year old currently doing a research project/internship, and I've just started 2 weeks ago. So I'm extremely confused. I've pretty much only got to this point by brute force. Please let me know if you need any other information.

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8080", "pyaudio:app"]
```

When I try to open the URL provided, it says "Service not available".

The URL is: https://internship-aiffpkop5q-as.a.run.app/

The logs I'm receiving in Cloud Run Logs when I try to open the URL are:

````
2021-11-24T03:55:09.124682Z [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)

2021-11-24T03:55:09.124702Z [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync

2021-11-24T03:55:09.149832Z [2] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2

2021-11-24T03:55:09.157491Z [2] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

2021-11-24T03:55:09.157955Z 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker worker.init_process() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process self.load_wsgi() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi self.callable = self.load() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load return self.load_wsgiapp() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app mod = importlib.import_module(module) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

2021-11-24T03:55:09.157964Z [2] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2)

2021-11-24T03:55:09.224921Z [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2021-11-24T03:55:09.225071Z [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2021-11-24T03:55:09.233682ZGET503978 B927 msChrome 95 https://internship-aiffpkop5q-as.a.run.app/

2021-11-24T03:55:09.522511ZGET5000 B0 msChrome 95 https://internship-aiffpkop5q-as.a.run.app/favicon.ico```
````

Comment: The error is caused by a missing **pyaudio** package. Review the **requirements.txt** file and add that dependency. Save time and test on your local system using Docker. Then deploy to Cloud Run.

Comment: @Ananth NM Do you know how to switch the python interpreter in the VSCode? Open Command Palette -> `Python: Select Interpreter`.

Comment: I don't know anything about **pyaudio**. However, you can specify the version of a package in requirements.txt. Review the history and requirements of pyaudio to figure out what is required for Python 3.9. Another option is to upgrade to Python 3.10.

Comment: Setup a Python virtual environment and Docker on your development system. Test your software before deploying to Google.

Answer (score 0):

**"pyaudio" package** is missing (not installed) according to the message below from your logs:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

So, you need to install **"pyaudio"**:

```
pip install pyaudio
```